# Can I get a specific example of XML in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to pull multiple elements out of an XML documents and their children but I cannot find a useful example anywhere... MSDN is very vague. This is c# in .Net

I am creating this XML dynamically already and transferring it to a string. I have been trying to use XmlNode with a NodeList to go through each file in a foreach section but It is not working properly.

Here is some sample XML:

```
<searchdoc>
    <results>
        <result no = "1">
            <url>a.com</url>
            <lastmodified>1/1/1</lastmodified>
            <description>desc1</description>
            <title>title1</title>
        </result>
        <result no = "2">
            <url>b.com</url>
            <lastmodified>2/2/2/</lastmodified>
            <description>desc2</description>
            <title>title2</title>
        </result>
    </results>
</searchdoc>
```

I need to pull each of the full paths `<result>`

Comment: XmlNode is the older XML API. Use XDocumnent et al if you're on FX3.5 and up.

Comment: You haven't shown the code you're trying to use, so it's hard to see what's wrong. As Henk says, LINQ to XML is a much simpler API than the old DOM one - I'd highly encourage you to use it if you can.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: _"I'd highly encourage you to use"_ a vendor lock-in method...

Comment: @Alejandro: Vendor lock-in as opposed to the rest of the .NET API?

Comment: @Christofer: Good question, +1. See my answer for a 9-line XSLT solution -- much simpler and shorter than anything else offered in the answers. When processing XML, remember: XSLT provides the simplest, shortest and most powerful solutions -- often in cases when with other languages one would give up or waste a lot of time to produce a suboptimal, unreadable and difficult to maintain solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **multiple ways to solve this problem,** depending on **which version of the .NET Framework** you are working on:

### .NET 1.x, 2.0 and 3.0

You can easily obtain a filtered list of nodes from your XML document by issuing an XPath query via the [XPathDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd8x668f.aspx):

```
using (var reader = new StringReader("<Results><Result>...</Result></Results>"))
{
  var document = new XPathDocument(reader);
  var navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
  var results = navigator.Select("//result");

  while (results.MoveNext())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", results.Current.Name, results.Current.Value);
  }
}
```

### .NET 3.5 and later

You should use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to query and filter XML hierarchies, since it offers a much more expressive API than the [XPath syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

```
var document = XDocument.Parse("<Results><Result>...</Result></Results>");
var results = document.Elements("result");

foreach (var item in results)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", item.Name, item.Value);
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [How to query XML with an XPath expression by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333)
- [LINQ to XML Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)
- [Comparison of XPath and LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675156.aspx)

Comment: +1 for good explanations and not assuming .Net 3.5+. Not all of us have had the luxury of moving off of 2.0 yet...

Answer (score 1):

If your document is not too big (I think it's not, as you're already generating it dinamically), couldn't you simply use LINQ to Xml?

```
XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Parse(myXmlString);
foreach(var result in myDoc.Descendants("result"))
{
  DoStuffWithTitle(result.Element("Title").Value);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XElement.Parse() ( or XDocument.Parse(), but I use it only when you have a proper xml document )

```
string doc = @"<searchdoc>
<results>
<result no = '1'>
<url>a.com</url>
<lastmodified>1/1/1</lastmodified>
<description>desc1</description>
<title>title1</title>
</result>
<result no = '2'>
<url>b.com</url>
<lastmodified>2/2/2/</lastmodified>
<description>desc2</description>
<title>title2</title>
</result>
</results>
</searchdoc>

";
var element = XElement.Parse(doc);
foreach (var result in element.Descendants("result"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(result.Element("url").Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using Linq to Xml or the XmlDocument API.

With XmlDocument you can do:

```
string xml = GetXmlFromFile();
var xDoc = XmlDocument.Load(xml);
var nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes('//result');
```

or with linq to xml (XDocument api)

```
string xml = GetXmlFromFile();
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xml);

var nodes = from x in xDoc.Descendants("result")
            select x;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating this XML dynamically
>   already and transferring it to a
>   string. ... I need to pull each of the
>   full paths `<result>`

If you just need the serealized `<result>` elements of the XML document, **probably the simplest way to do this is with this XSLT transformation** (read your MSDN documentation for examples how to perform an XSLT transformation (the **[XslCompiledTransform.Transform()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.transform.aspx)** method)) in C#:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/result"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<searchdoc>
    <results>
        <result no = "1">
            <url>a.com</url>
            <lastmodified>1/1/1</lastmodified>
            <description>desc1</description>
            <title>title1</title>
        </result>
        <result no = "2">
            <url>b.com</url>
            <lastmodified>2/2/2/</lastmodified>
            <description>desc2</description>
            <title>title2</title>
        </result>
    </results>
</searchdoc>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<result no="1">
  <url>a.com</url>
  <lastmodified>1/1/1</lastmodified>
  <description>desc1</description>
  <title>title1</title>
</result>
<result no="2">
  <url>b.com</url>
  <lastmodified>2/2/2/</lastmodified>
  <description>desc2</description>
  <title>title2</title>
</result>
```